# Artifactory ldaps wrong url/port

Tags: ldap, artifactory

We are using Artifactory 6.18.0 Pro, and authenticating using ldap on port 3268. Everything working fine.
Now, we try to change the ldap authentication to ldap**s** on port 636, then getting error `wrong url/port` on artifactory UI. While checking the `artifacoty.log` found more detail error,

```
[Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Found the `ca-certificates.crt` and `java/cacerts` and update the `ca-certificates.crt` and import our self signed certificate to the java keystore cacerts. Restart the artificatory - gettting the same above described again.

Does anybody know where is the Java-keystore or certificate path for Artifactory running under docker. To note that ldaps server is running smooth and is serving to other client.

Answer (score 0):

I understood that Artifactory is installed as docker container, where the self-signed certs copied to the container? Kindly refer to the below 2 articles which will help in setting up LDAPS,

1. https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-use-a-custom-java-truststore-cacerts-in-a-artifactory-docker-container/
2. https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-configure-ldap-with-tls-in-aritfactory/